# Where i can change shader uniforms and call GL Functions?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I am just trying to write simple android app with GLSurfaceView but i have one problem.
I wrote simple shader program ant put there one float parameter. This is my

**Vertex shader:**

```
        attribute vec2 vPosition;
        attribute vec2 vTexCoord;
        varying vec2 texCoord;

        void main(){
           texCoord = vTexCoord;
           gl_Position = vec4 ( vPosition.x, vPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0 );
        }
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
        precision mediump float;
        uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
        uniform float myParam;
        varying vec2 texCoord;

        void main(){
          gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture,texCoord);
          gl_FragColor.r = gl_FragColor.r*myParam.x;
        }
```

*All works great.*

I got the handle to have access to myParam (int paramHandle - member of my class.):

```
        public void onSurfaceCreated(....){
          ....
          paramHandle= GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"myParam");
          ....
        }
```

Now i want to variate myParam and watch what happens whit the image on the screen. For this task i need to call:

```
 GLES20.glUseProgram(myShaderProgram);
 GLES20.glUniform1f(paramHandle, new_value);
```

So: if i try to change myParam value inside on of these functions:

**onSurfaceCreated(...), onSurfaceChanged(...) or in onDrawFrame(...)**

i can see this changes on the screen, so i feel that myParam value was changed.

**But if i want to set maParam value using button, for example call function *setMyParamValue* when button was clicked:**

```
    public void setMyParamValue(float newValue){
      GLES20.glUseProgram(myShaderProgram);
      GLES20.glUniform1f(paramHandle, new_value);
    }
```

**it seems that nothing happens.**

Can someone explain me how it works? Why i cannot set uniform value inside my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering happens on the different thread than where the UI events are passed from. openGL calls should only happen from the render thread.

You should forward those calls to a runnable that you pass to `queueEvent`:

```
public void setMyParamValue(final float newValue){
    queueEvent(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
           GLES20.glUseProgram(myShaderProgram);
           GLES20.glUniform1f(paramHandle, new_value);
        }
    });
}
```

The code inside `run()` will get executed in the render thread.

Comment: Ohh, i have thought about it, but i couldn`t find any proofs of it... Thank you very much :)