# RxJava observeOn currentThread to call opengl functions

Tags: android, asynchronous, opengl-es, rx-java

I'm developing a simple game for learning.
I'm reading a lot of images from a file and than loading it to the GL environment, it takes like 10 seconds so I looked for something similar to asyncio in python to reduce time and found RxJava library that many people use for asynchronous functionality.

This is something that I do onSurfaceChanged in my GLSurfaceView

```
Log.d("THREAD", "processing item on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
List<NXNode> tileList = new ArrayList();
src.getChild("tile").iterator().forEachRemaining(tileList::add);
Observable.just(tileList)
        .flatMapIterable(child -> child)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(tilenode -> Observable.just(new Tile((NXNode) tilenode, tileset)))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext(tile -> {Log.d("THREAD", "processing item on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                           tile.loadGLTexture();})
        .subscribe(tile -> putTile((Byte) tile.getZ(), tile));
```

when I draw my images I see black squares because the loading images happens in another thread
This is the output:

```
2020-08-28 17:53:59.238 6857-7076/com.bapplications.maplemobile D/THREAD: processing item on thread GLThread 139526
2020-08-28 17:53:59.252 6857-6857/com.bapplications.maplemobile D/THREAD: processing item on thread main
2020-08-28 17:53:59.298 6857-6857/com.bapplications.maplemobile D/THREAD: processing item on thread main
2020-08-28 17:53:59.303 6857-6857/com.bapplications.maplemobile D/THREAD: processing item on thread main
2020-08-28 17:53:59.324 6857-6857/com.bapplications.maplemobile D/THREAD: processing item on thread main
.
.
.
```

What scheduler I need to use to make the doOnNext run on my current thread.

Couldn't find any solution or any documented information about it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I am late to the party, but maybe this answer will help someone else. Look at [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33630967/5531164). In short, you should not call `tile.loadGLTexture()` method on the main thread, but "ask" the `GLSurfaceView` to run your task on its own `GLThread`. Try the following:

```
.doOnNext(tile -> {
    this.queueEvent(() -> {
         Log.d("THREAD", "processing item on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
         tile.loadGLTexture();
    }
})
```